# Correct usage of dropout for LSTM and uncertainty estimation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have built an LSTM model which performs pretty well on my time series problem. What I am trying to do now is incorporate dropout and recurrent dropout to model the uncertainty around my predictions. From literature I have read, this should add noise to my predictions but the mean of these predictions shouldn't be too far from the values without using dropout during inference. In my case, when using dropout, even only 0.01, my prediction accuracy is approximately an order of magnitude larger than without dropout. For example, if i evaluate a single batch (16, 20, 14), without dropout the results are the same.

```
for x, y in test.take(1):
  for i in range(10):
    encoder_decoder_dropout.evaluate(x, y)

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0584 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0584
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0584 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0584
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0584 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0584
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0584 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0584
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0584 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0584
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0584 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0584
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0584 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0584
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0584 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0584
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0584 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0584
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0584 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0584
```

However, adding dropout of 0.1, I see the stochasticity in my results, but terrible accuracy:

```
for x, y in test.take(1):
  for i in range(10):
    encoder_decoder_dropout.evaluate(x, y)

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5677 - mean_absolute_error: 0.5677
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5512 - mean_absolute_error: 0.5512
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6085 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6085
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6091 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6091
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6503 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6503
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5438 - mean_absolute_error: 0.5438
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5882 - mean_absolute_error: 0.5882
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6500 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6500
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6235 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6235
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6119 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6119
```

My model is below. I am wondering if this is expected behaviour, or if I have implemented this poorly for MCdropout.

```
input= keras.Input(shape=(60))
x = layers.RepeatVector(30, input_shape=[60])(input)
x = layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, dropout=0.1, 
                                                    recurrent_dropout=0.1,
                                                     return_sequences=False))(x, training=True)
x = layers.Dense(look_forward*num_features,
                        kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.glorot_normal())(x)
output = layers.Reshape([look_forward, num_features])(x)

decoder_dropout = keras.Model(input, output, name="decoder_dropout")

encoder_decoder_dropout = tf.keras.Sequential([encoder, decoder_dropout])
encoder_decoder_dropout.set_weights(encoder_decoder_dropout_trained.get_weights()) 

encoder_decoder_dropout.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),
                  optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])
```

Comment: just asking to make sure i'm on track did u fit your model on the training data? i'm asking cause i see u seem to be evaluating on some test data.

Comment: Hi. Yes I trained on training data. I am evaluating on a hold out test set.